# Django-import-export get auto generated id during import

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-import-export

I am trying to import an excel without an ID field specified and the ID is being auto genetrated by django. I need to access this auto generated ID field but i cannot figure out how to do it. accessing the entire row doesnot give the auto generated ID. Any ideas on how to access the auto generated ID field?

Comment: Do you need this ID before django creates the object? or after?

Comment: I needed the auto ID duing the import process as explained by Matthew in the first answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to access the auto id during the import process.  If this is not correct, please clarify your questions and provide [more information](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

There is a post-save hook called [`after_save_instance()`](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_resources.html#import_export.resources.Resource.after_save_instance).  The `instance` is the instantiated instance of the model object created from each row in your import.  At this point, the instance will have been saved, and will have its auto-generated pk set.

```py
class YourResource(resources.ModelResource):

  def after_save_instance(self, instance, using_transactions, dry_run):
    # the model instance will have been saved at this point, and will have a pk
    print(instance.pk)

  class Meta:
    model = YourModel
```

Comment: Thanks alot @Matthew . This is what I was looking for. Cheers